# dblogin cannot connect to SYSTEM DSN

Tags: sql-server, oracle-19c, goldengate

I'm trying to install golden 19.1.0.0 on Window Server. I try to connect to SQL Server 2019 with dblogin and got the error in the picture. Any idea how to solve it?
[image]

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for detailed messages as to why the login failed and add it to your question if it's not self-explanatory.

Comment: Please post the text information as text.  I will allow someone to google it for you.